# Get random posts through WordPress API

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am building a self-test project which can give 10 questions at one time from a question list. I want the 10 questions should be different every time I start the test. The front-end is React and the back-end is WordPress by using WordPress API.

Previously I used `orderby=rand` in the query by implementing a [plug-in](https://felipeelia.dev/wordpress-rest-api-enable-random-order-of-posts-list/?unapproved=2092&moderation-hash=82ac49bd55ebd051eba1b4fc69e8217e#comment-2092)

```
<?php

/**

 * Plugin Name: REST API - Post list randomize

 * Description: Randomize the content list in REST API passing `orderby=rand` as parameter.

 * Version:     1.0.0

 * Author:      Felipe Elia | Codeable

 * Author URI:  https://codeable.io/developers/felipe-elia?ref=qGTOJ

 */



/**

 * Add `rand` as an option for orderby param in REST API.

 * Hook to `rest_{$this->post_type}_collection_params` filter.

 *

 * @param array $query_params Accepted parameters.

 * @return array

 */

function add_rand_orderby_rest_post_collection_params( $query_params ) {

    $query_params['orderby']['enum'][] = 'rand';

    return $query_params;

}

add_filter( 'rest_post_collection_params', 'add_rand_orderby_rest_post_collection_params' );
```

It worked perfectly until 2 weeks ago. Without modifying any code, it was just broken. I used Postman to test, such as `http://localhost/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/questions?per_page=10&orderby=rand`. The response is

```
    "code": "rest_invalid_param",
        "message": "Invalid parameter(s): orderby",
        "data": {
            "status": 400,
            "params": {
                "orderby": "orderby is not one of author, date, id, include, modified, parent, relevance, slug, include_slugs, title."
            }
        }
```

Two weeks ago if I used the same query, it could give me 10 random questions. It looks like the plug-in cannot add `rand` successfully as a parameter for `orderby` in WordPress like before.

BTW, the functionality of `orderby=rand` in WP isn't broken because if I manually add `rand` as a parameter in WP core code, the above query can work again.

Does anybody know what's wrong with the plug-in or some latest updates in WP causing the problem?

Another thing is I saw some articles mentioning ORDERBY = RAND() in MySQL will affect the performance severely when the database is large. So I wonder whether I should use `orderby=rand` in the query to get random questions or think about other ways to do the job. Does anybody have any suggestions for this performance issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. I need to make the first parameter `rest_post_collection_params` of `add_filter` function to the correspondent post type.

The original `rest_post_collection_params` is for the WP default **posts** type. Because I use ACF(Advanced Custom Fields, another plug-in to create customized post types) to create my own post types, such as **books**, I need to change the first parameter to `rest_books_collection_params`. If you have more customized post types, just create as many as `add_filter` functions for each of them.

Just have no ideas why I could use `rest_post_collection_params` for all my customized post types 3 weeks ago but not now. Anyway, since it is solved, don't bother. My project is more front-end oriented. WP is just storage.

BTW, probably someone has noticed that `rest_post_collection_params` is for the WP default post type **posts**. In the parameter it uses single form **post** for the plural form **posts**. This only works for the WP default post type. For customized types, if it is **books**, the parameter should be rest_**books**_collection_param; if **questions**, then rest_**questions**_collection_param. Keep the parameter exactly the same as the post type.

Answer (score 0):

**For Getting Unique Questions:**

```
table: wp_question_filter_list

id  ip_address question_list
1   1.21.23    1,2,3,4,5
2   1.21.24    1,4,6,7,8    
3   1.21.25    4,5,6,8,9    



function get_unique_questions($ip_address){
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'question_filter_list'; 


$unique_id_list=$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE  ip_address=%d",$ip_address), ARRAY_A);


    if (count($unique_id_list) > 0) {
    $question_data=$unique_id_list[0];

    $arr_question=array();
    if(isset($question_data['question_list']) && $question_data['question_list']!=''){
        $arr_old_question_id_list=explode(",",$question_data['question_list']);
    }

$excludes = implode(',', $arr_old_question_id_list);
$arr_question_id_list=$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE ip_address='".$ip_address."' AND id NOT IN('".$excludes."') "), ARRAY_A);
set_unique_questions($ip_address,$arr_question_id_list);
}

function set_unique_questions($ip_address,$arr_question_id_list){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'question_filter_list'; 
    $unique_id_list=$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE  ip_address=%d",$ip_address), ARRAY_A);


    if (count($unique_id_list) > 0) {
    $question_data=$unique_id_list[0];

    $arr_question=array();
    if(isset($question_data['question_list']) && $question_data['question_list']!=''){
        $arr_old_question_id_list=explode(",",$question_data['question_list']);
    }

      if(is_array($arr_question_id_list) && !empty($arr_question_id_list)){     
           foreach($arr_question_id_list as $single_question){
               array_push($arr_question,$single_question);
          }
      }
      $str_question_id_list=implode(",",$arr_question);


   $wpdb->update($table_name, array(
        'question_list' => $str_question_id_list
    ), array(
        'ip_address' => $ip_address
    ));


    }else{

     $str_question_id_list=implode(",",$arr_question_id_list);
     $data = array(
        'ip_address' => $ip_address,
        'question_list' => $str_question_id_list,
    );
     $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data);

   }



$result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $item);
}

$ip_address=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


$arr_question_list=get_unique_questions($ip_address);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr_question_list);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually I don't care too much every time it gives a set of completely different questions from the last time. If the result is random, it will be OK even if some questions are the same.
Additionally, because I use WordPress API, I don't use SQL query language directly, but just query string like `http://localhost/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/questions?per_page=10&orderby=rand` through API. Basically, it's an app more front-end. The SQL query is too back-ended that I try to avoid.